# Android studio, setting Retry to another activity

Tags: javascript, android-studio, canvas, android-intent

I would like to reset the game so i come to my main.class and not that it resets. I tried to set public void reset to a intent but dont work, any ideas?

Now the game pop up a message and when i press it just restarts

```
public void reset() {
    playerPoint = new Point(Constants.SCREEN_WIDTH/2, 3*Constants.SCREEN_HEIGHT/4);
    player.update(playerPoint);
    obstacleManager = new ObstacleManager(200, 350, 75, Color.BLACK);
    movingplayer = false;

}



@Override
public void terminate(){
    SceneManager.ACTIVE_SCENE = 0;

}

@Override
public void recivietouch(MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()){
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if(!gameOver && player.getRectangle().contains((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY()))
                movingplayer = true;
            if(gameOver && System.currentTimeMillis() - gameOverTime >= 2000){
                reset();
                gameOver = false;
            }
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            if(!gameOver && movingplayer)
                playerPoint.set((int)event.getX(), (int)event.getY());
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            movingplayer = false;
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: could you expound more

Comment: I follow a guide on youtube where you control the character with your finger and try to avoid the falls coming from the top of the screen. I now get a text "Game Over" when i crash into a wall and when i click it resets the game, i want i to go to another activity instead of reseting